# Why doesn't xbutton.PerformClick() work in silverlight?

Tags: c#, button, silverlight-4.0, click

I need Button.click from another class but doesn't work pickButton.PerformClick()?

```
[Category("Özel")]
[DefaultValue(null)]
public Button pickButton { get; set; }


protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyUp(e);
    if (e.Key == Key.F10)
    {
        if (pickButton != null)
        {
            //pickButton.PerformClick() ??
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`PerformClick` isn't available in Silverlight.

Why don't you extract the code from the `pickButton` click event and call that from both places:

```
protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyUp(e);
    if (e.Key == Key.F10)
    {
        if (pickButton != null)
        {
            DoStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
private void pickButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

Obviously `DoStuff()` is a placeholder to illustrate the concept.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight does not support that operation. Call the click event directly i.e

```
pickButton.pickButton_Click(this, null);
```

or

```
 button2_Click(this, null);
```